# How to Create jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I want make jqgrid in dynamic.
so i have one variable 
in which 
i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ok').click(function(){
    var Str='jQuery("#list").jqGrid({ url:'server.php', datatype: "json", colNames:['...'], colModel:[ {...}], rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30], pager: '#pager2', sortname: 'id', viewrecords: true, sortorder: "desc", caption:"JSON Example" });'
});
</script>
<html>
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</html>
```

How send Request of jqgrid?

Comment: need to wrap code your in `document.ready`

Comment: @charlietfl Means My click event is in the $(document).ready() function.I did that but not working

Comment: `$('ok')` is invalid selector also

Comment: @charlietfl NOw edit the Code it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually force a reload of the grid by:

```
jQuery('#list').jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]);
```

In fact may I suggest that you fully build the grid on the load of the page, with the datatype set to `datatype: local` and then on your click event you can just

```
jQuery('#list_container').show();
jQuery('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json', url: '/server.php' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]);
```

This way you jqGrid is sitting there, hidden and waiting to be loaded when you click.  If the datatype is set to local it will not attempt to load any information till you click.

Comment: i want make three in one Grid.So On Click I have Generate Variable like 'Str.and Make Grid.Is it possible?

Comment: You want to make 3 grids on one click? If I understand it would be the exact same as above. You could trigger multiple reloads or have the 3 grids initialized when your page loads, hidden and then shown and loaded when you click your button.

Comment: make three grid but not a same time.

Comment: Then follow my second block, setup all three grids when you page loads, have them hidden with `data: local` and then when you deal with the events to show the grids set the `datatype, url,` and trigger a reload.